# How does gearman distinguish two jobs?

Tags: c++, c, gearman

In our scenario, we launch multiple gearman servers, and using multiple threads to assign jobs to workers. In below API function, the `unique` parameter is given the default value of `NULL`.

`void *gearman_client_do(gearman_client_st *client, const char *function_name, const char *unique, const void *workload, size_t workload_size, size_t *result_size, gearman_return_t *ret_ptr);`

So what we observed here is that, if two jobs are distributed at the same time, then gearman servers would mess up these two. Whichever job was finished earlier, would be returned as the result of both jobs.

Is this true, that gearman will use the time stamp to  distinguish different jobs if the `unique` in `gearman_client_do()` is assigned to `NULL`?

EDIT: type `gearman_client_do`

Comment: What does the gearman documentation say?

Answer (score 0):

> The unique ID can be used by the server to reduce queue length. If a
>   job with the same Unique ID has already been submitted, the server may
>   attach this request to the already existing job. This includes jobs
>   already in progress, in which case non-background jobs will be sent
>   the same result as background jobs. This is known commonly as
>   "coalescing".

[gearman protocol](http://gearman.org/protocol/) description of unique id handling.

> Is this true, that gearman will use the time stamp to distinguish
>   different jobs if the unique in gearman_client_do() is assigned to
>   NULL?

Time stamp is the matter for the jobs order in the queue. `gearmand` would execute each job without unique id.
See also [implementation of gearman_client_do](https://github.com/gearman/gearmand/blob/a4c04a22f08d827dd52d4b00c286a95fb2b8482c/libgearman/client.cc#L663)